# How do I create a SQL table when a column receives a list?

Tags: java, sql

I'm starting to learn SQL and I need to create a table based on a java entity but one of the arguments from a class is a list of another class.

This is are the code:

```
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal value;
}

public class order {
    private Long id;
    private Person person;
    private List<orderItem> itens;
}

public class PedidoItem {
    private long id;
    private Product product;
    private int quantity;
    private Order order;
}
```

And this is the script I was creating:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
    description VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    value NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE order (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_person INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES person(id),
    itens  " <- I don't know how to complete this! ";
);

CREATE TABLE orderItem (
    id INT AUTO_INCREENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_product INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES product(id),
    quantity INT(999999) NOT NULL,
    id_order INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES order(id)
);
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Your table definitions are partly product specific.)

Comment: You don't need any changes in order table, only first 2 columns means id and id_person is fine. As your orderItem table will take care of mapping.

Answer (score 0):

When you see a collection of child objects owned by a parent, that means there's a one-to-many relationship between the entities. You'll need parent and child tables, with a foreign key relationship to the parent in the child table. There will be zero or more rows in the child table for each row in the parent table.

You have it right in your design.  There's no need for the `order` table to know about the `orderItem` table.  The child table needs to [refer](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) to the parent.

```
CREATE TABLE order (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_person INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES person(id),;
);

CREATE TABLE orderItem (
    id INT AUTO_INCREENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_product INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES product(id),
    quantity INT(999999) NOT NULL,
    id_order INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES order(id)
);
```